# restart apache under www-data user in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, httpd, saas, www-data

I have a SaaS webapp service, so each time a new client is registered in my registration app, it creates a new subdomain and a new apache virtualhost config file, to enable this configuration I need to restart apache (is running on port 8080), how ever if I try to run either `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `apache2ctl restart` under www-data (this is the user that is running my app) I get the following error:

```
Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How could I restart automatically apache?

OS is Ubuntu Server 10.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this to your sudoers file and then simply use sudo to you call the apache restart command.

```
Cmnd_Alias AP2RESTART=/etc/init.d/apache2
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: AP2RESTART
```